# measurable sets

Tags: measure-theory

please could you help me with this exercise.

Prove or a counterexample to the following statement:

$f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ such that $\forall \alpha  \in \mathbb{R}$ the set $\{ x  \in \mathbb{R} : f(x)=\alpha \} $ is measurable. then $f$ is measurable.

thank you very much in advance.

Comment: See @AsafKaragila's answer to this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/264668/must-f-be-measurable-if-each-f-1c-is

Comment: Looks like this is a duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

An injective function is not necessarily measurable, but for an injective function the set $\{x \in \Bbb{R} : f(x)=\alpha\}$ always contains a single element and is thus measurable.